Filtering and ellipse fitting noisy images
I have images as shown below (Figure 1) and I would like to fit two ellipses to the inner and outer shapes.
Raw data:

Edit
New code with fmw42's suggestions
if img is None:
    print("Failed to load the image")
    exit()


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
masked = cv2.inRange(gray,100,255)
ksize= 15
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(masked,ksize = ksize)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

def detect_ellipses(img, contours):
    ellipses = []
    for contour in contours:
        relevant_points = np.reshape(contour, (contour.shape[0], 2))
        try:
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(relevant_points)
            print(ellipse)
            ellipses.append(ellipse)
        except:
            pass
            
    return ellipses


# # Apply edge detection to the grayscale image with adjusted parameters
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 255)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(edges)
plt.show()
# # # Find the contours in the edge map
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

The results after applying Canny and after fitting


I'm still encountering the issues of unwanted contours in final result. Unfornately, I can't really filter those out because some of the shapes are too closed to the desired ones.
if img is None:
    print("Failed to load the image")
    exit()


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,65,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ksize = 15
med=  cv2.medianBlur(thresh, ksize = ksize)

def detect_ellipses(img, contours):
    ellipses = []
    for contour in contours:
        relevant_points = np.reshape(contour, (contour.shape[0], 2))
        try:
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(relevant_points)
            #print(ellipse)
            ellipses.append(ellipse)
        except:
            pass
            
    return ellipses


# # Apply edge detection to the grayscale image with adjusted parameters
edges = cv2.Canny(med, 65, 255)

# # # Find the contours in the edge map
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# plt.figure('outer')
# plt.imshow(contours)
# plt.show()

# # # Detect ellipses from the contours
ellipses = detect_ellipses(img, contours)


# # Draw the ellipses on the original image
for ellipse in ellipses:
    try:
        cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print(ellipse)
    except:
        pass

# #Show the original image with the fitted ellipses
cv2.imshow('Ellipse Detection', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


I have been using OpenCV and am able to consistently fit the inner ellipse. The outer has been tricky due to the noises that I have not been able to remove completely, which cause undesired fittings (Figure 2). Currently, I am able to fit individual images through trial and error, but not ideal.


One of your problems is that the inner black curve is not an ellipse it is an egg shape. One end is considerably smaller radius of curvature than the other. Once you have the right shape consider using a scale factor to find the other outer contour.

Threshold after your median blur. Use cv2.inrange() on the gray values in the median blur for the bright ring

Quick question: why do you want to "fit" a shape to the contour? What's your aim? You don't really need to fit anything to get information from this image, such as the width and height of your object in different locations.

Also, please supply an unaltered image (not an image of a plot, nor one with already drawn circles)

@TinoD I'm interested in approximating the inner and outer "diameters". Since the shape can range from circular to oval, I want to be able to obtain the largest and smallest diameters of each shape. I'm unfamiliar with image fitting, and this seems to be the approach most tutorials take. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

@fmw42 I applied your suggestion and I'm now able to fit the outer ellipse/oval. However, I still have a problem with the unwanted fits.

I still don't see source data. [mre] required.

@ChristophRackwitz hmm didn't go through previously. It's there now. Thanks!

@BQUNguy. Can you not filter on the area or shape of the contour. Show your new result and threshold result. You can also use morphology to filter out small unwanted regions if not too large. But the contour area is usually best for throwing out small unwanted regions.

@fmw42 Sorry I don't quite follow. You mean perform all the operations on the whole photo with the ROI excluded? If possible, could you please scribe up a quick algo of what you described? Thanks!

@BQUNguy.  No, I simply meant to filter out small contours by using the contour areas to do the filtering. If smaller than your desired good contours, then filter them out before fitting ellipse to the contours.

@fmw42 I tried your suggestion and the results were much better. However, I'm still running into issues with consistency and it's mainly because of the image quality. The intensity range of the pixels changes. For example, inRange(low,high) would work great for a set of images but fail on others. Maybe I need a way to specify the threshold range dynamically?

You could analyze the histogram and find a range from there

@fmw42 hooray! The fit has 90% accuracy now! Thanks for your help!

Post your improved code as an answer to help others in the future.
